collisionResolution truncate is not working for AxisValueLabel in Charts framework SwiftUI
I tried collisionResolution as truncate in AxisValueLabel. As documented in apple, Truncate a label to the space available to it but it's not working.
import Charts
import SwiftUI

struct YAxisLabel: View {
    
    let workoutData = [
        (workoutType: "Walk", data: Workout.walkWorkout),
        (workoutType: "Run", data: Workout.runWorkout)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Chart {
                ForEach(workoutData, id: \.workoutType) { element in
                    ForEach(element.data) {
                        BarMark(
                            x: .value("Day", $0.day),
                            y: .value("Workout(in minutes)", $0.minutes)
                        )
                    }
                    .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Workout(type)", element.workoutType))
                    .position(by: .value("Workout(type)", element.workoutType)) // Asif - this craetes grouped
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 200)
            .chartYAxis {
                AxisMarks(position: .leading) {
                    axis in
                    AxisGridLine()
                    AxisValueLabel(
                        centered: true,
                        collisionResolution: .truncate,
                        orientation: AxisValueLabelOrientation.verticalReversed
                    ) {
                        Text("\(axis.index * 25) minutes")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct Workout: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let day: String
    let minutes: Int
}

extension Workout {
    static let walkWorkout: [Workout] = [
        .init(day: NSLocalizedString("mon", comment: ""), minutes: 23),
        .init(day: "Tue", minutes: 35),
        .init(day: "Wed", minutes: 55),
        .init(day: "Thu", minutes: 30),
        .init(day: "Fri", minutes: 15),
        .init(day: "Sat", minutes: 65),
        .init(day: "Sun", minutes: 81),
    ]
    
    static let runWorkout: [Workout] = [
        .init(day: NSLocalizedString("mon", comment: ""), minutes: 16),
        .init(day: "Tue", minutes: 12),
        .init(day: "Wed", minutes: 55),
        .init(day: "Thu", minutes: 34),
        .init(day: "Fri", minutes: 22),
        .init(day: "Sat", minutes: 43),
        .init(day: "Sun", minutes: 90),
    ]
}

Issue: Labels are getting override on each other.
It should be truncated as per Apple doc
collisionResolution: .truncate => Truncate a label to the space available to it.
I want to do 2 things here -

Either text should be cropped
Or Area should be expended as per large label

Please find the screenshot as below -


The collisionResolution doesn't seem to work satisfactorily in this situation from what I can tell. Although adjusting the frame, fonts or a combination seems to get a decent result.
Changing the frame height from 200 to 300 to expand the row size:
    .frame(height: 300)

Chart with frame height 300:

Or if the original frame size of 200 must remain then changing the Axis font sizes seems to work too:
//Labels for y Axis
Text("\(axis.index * 25) minutes")
    .font(.system(size: 7))

//Labels for x Axis
.chartXAxis {
    AxisMarks {
        AxisValueLabel()
        .font(.system(size: 7))
    }
}

Chart with reduced font size:

